# Why I am getting "cannot read property style of null" error?

Tags: javascript

I am not able to understand why it is giving

> uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" at line 38

when I am moving the mouse pointer at all the divs. Every time I move the pointer at a div, I get the error.

Please explain what is the issue.

```js
var top = "p3";

function toTop(newTop) {
  var domTop = document.getElementById(top).style;
  var domNew = document.getElementById(newTop).style;
  domTop.zIndex = "0";
  domNew.zIndex = "10";
  top = document.getElementById(newTop).id;
}
```

```css
.para1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10;
  left: 120;
  z-index: 0;
  border: solid;
  padding: 80;
  width: 300;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.para2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50;
  left: 150;
  z-index: 0;
  border: solid;
  padding: 80;
  width: 300;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.para3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  left: 180;
  z-index: 0;
  border: solid;
  padding: 80;
  width: 300;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="z-index: 10;" class="para1" id="p1" onmouseover="toTop('p1')">Frame One</div>
<div style="z-index: 5;" class="para2" id="p2" onmouseover="toTop('p2')">Frame Two</div>
<div style="z-index: 0;" class="para3" id="p3" onmouseover="toTop('p3')">Frame Three</div>
```

Comment: @Fast Snail thanks for editing it. I was not able to do it in mobile.

Comment: rename the **reserved** and readonly var `top` to `myTop` - it gives errors since window.top is the handle for the main window

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. It worked.

Comment: `top` is reserve word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename the **readonly** var `top` to for example `myTop` - it gives errors since window.top is the handle for the main window

```
var myTop = "p3";

function toTop(newTop) {
  var domTop = document.getElementById(myTop).style;
  var domNew = document.getElementById(newTop).style;
  domTop.zIndex = "0";
  domNew.zIndex = "10";
  myTop = document.getElementById(newTop).id;
}
```

I could not find `top` to be **reserved** in the official documentation but it does belong to the list of words to avoid since it is readonly in the browser implementations.

Answer (score 2):

`top` is a reserved identifier in JavaScript, so you can't use it as a variable name. It means that in this function:

```
function toTop(newTop) {
    // here `top` points to `window`
    var domTop=document.getElementById(top).style;
    var domNew=document.getElementById(newTop).style;
    domTop.zIndex="0";
    domNew.zIndex="10";
    top=document.getElementById(newTop).id;
}
```

`top` is pointing to the `window` object, that's why `document.getElementById(top)` returns `null`.

Comment: I don't think it's a type. The OP didn't know that `top` is a reserved word.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't classify intentionally written code as a typo. This question is valuable.

Comment: @4castle why is it valuable? it is a typo

Comment: @KeyurShah It's not a typography error: it's not knowing about `window.top`. I doubt their finger slipped and they accidentally typed `top`.

Comment: I marked as typo in lack of a "you cannot use that word" Anyway. There are now enough answers and comments that shows this here.

Comment: I didn't know that top is a keyword. I am new to JavaScript. Thanks for the answers guys...

Answer (score 0):

"top" is a reserved keyword defines the frame top, replace variable name "top" with something else like below.

```
var top1 = "p3";

function toTop(newTop) {
  var domTop = document.getElementById(top1).style;
  var domNew = document.getElementById(newTop).style;
  domTop.zIndex = "0";
  domNew.zIndex = "10";
  top1 = document.getElementById(newTop).id;
}
```

Comment: 2 things in your code: **1/.** There is nothing what is called `top2`, so, shall you rename `top1` to another name? **2/.** You need to update line `top = document.getElementById(newTop).id;`